# Is there any way to identify a VC++ Projects using Dot Net or not?

Tags: .net, visual-c++, clr

I have couple of VC++ Projects and their outputs as dll or exes. I need to identify which dll/exes  or which VCProjects are using Dot Net? which means I want to know any VC projects are using managed code?

I know one way is /clr switch is used for vcprojects which uses Dot net. Is there any chance without /clr switch VCProjects can use Dot Net?

Comment: You can try to open the output DLL or EXE in Reflector, it'll tell you if a file contains managed code or not.

Comment: @Dai: Where can get the reflector?

Answer (score 1):

Yes - even if a project does not create a .NET assembly by using the `\clr` switch, it is still possible that it might use .NET.

1. An unmanaged DLL or EXE can use a .NET assembly exposed as a COM object - [see MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973872.aspx).
2. An unmanaged EXE can host a Windows Form - [see MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ahdd1h97%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

The second case is really a special example of the first - both are using COM as the interop mechanism.

Comment: Basically I need to identify these projects to follow a common way to change the assembly version.. Is the projects of these 2 catageries needs assmebly version ?

Comment: @RajeshSubramanian - no, these categories are native (unmanaged) modules that don't have .NET assembly information. As long as you are maintaining the assembly version on any .NET COM projects, you can ignore these cases.